# How to handle video popup in selenium webdriver c#

Tags: c#, selenium

I am trying to automate video visit application.
On clicking on 'start call' link, a new video popup appears on the exisitng/same browser window.

I am trying to automate video components by switching to the video popup(modal window), but switching is not happening

I tried switching to window, tried with switching to frame, tried with alerts, but nothing worked

HTML code

```
<div class="windowframe popup ui-draggable" style="visibility: visible; position: absolute; top: 20px; left: 514px; width: 1000px; z-index: 12; display: block;">
    <h2 class="title clearfix ui-draggable-handle">
        <span class="p-text">Video Consult</span>
        <button class="p-button p-button-close" name="close" tabindex="1">
            <div class="p-icon component icon-resolved">
                <svg style="" width="512px" height="512px" viewBox="0 0 512 512" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" x="0px"
                     y="0px">
                    <path d=""></path>
                </svg>
            </div>
        </button>
        <button class="p-button p-button-minimize" name="minimize" tabindex="1" style="display: none;">
            <div class="p-icon component icon-resolved">
                <svg style="" width="512px" height="512px" viewBox="0 0 512 512" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" x="0px"
                     y="0px">
                    <rect width="384" height="64" x="64" y="224"></rect>
                </svg>
            </div>
        </button>
    </h2>
    <div class="windowcontent" style="height: 396.2px;">
        <div control="ViewContainer" class="viewcontainer p-view-viewcontainer control p-view p-view-mode-view p-view-no-toolbar p-view-no-title"
             float="" style="height: 100%;"
             name="VideoWebRTCView" tabindex="0">
            <h2 class="p-container title component hide"><span class="p-text component hide">Video Consult</span>
                <div class="busyindicator">
                    <div class="p-icon component icon-resolved">
                        <div class="spinner">
                            <div class="spinner-circle"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </h2>
            <div class="p-content content" name="VideoWebRTCView" xmlns:petrel="urn:PetrelXslExtensions" xmlns:bind=" "
                 xmlns:fx="urn:ExpressionFunctions">
                <div control="iFrame" class="iframe p-view-iframe control p-view p-view-mode-view p-view-no-toolbar"
                     float="" style="height: 366px;" name="Video">
                    <iframe width="100%" height="100%" scrolling="auto" frameborder="0"
                            seamless="seamless" src=""></iframe>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="metadata"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="windowfooter clearfix">
        <div class="resize ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" style="position: absolute;">
        </div>
        <div class="footerText"></div>
        <div class="buttonholder"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The above HTML code is dynamic, on clicking on link the above code in div tag gets added to the body tag.

tried identifying the element as below, but its throwing noSuchElementException

```
WebDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[contains(@class,'windowframe')]"));
```

tried with switching to window, but here the size is always 1

```
List<string> listWindow = _context.WebDriver.WindowHandles.ToList();
            int size = listWindow.Count;
            Console.WriteLine("size: " + size);
            foreach (var handle in listWindow)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("window name: " + handle);
                if (!parentwindow.Equals(handle))
                {
                    _context.WebDriver.SwitchTo().Window(handle);
                }

            }
```

tried with switch to frame

```
 IWebElement frameele = _context.WebDriver.FindElement(By.Name("Video"));
                _context.WebDriver.SwitchTo().Frame(frameele);
```

Comment: Can you share url if it is not private. did you try with switch to iframe ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Since the video is not in another tab/window you don't have to get window handles and switch window.
- If the video is in the div with class `windowframe` and the div is not in another iframe then just try to access the div without changing focus.

  - If the that doesn't work try this
    `driver.SwitchTo().ActiveElement()`
- If the video is in a iframe then you have to switch to the iframe by passing the iframe element or the id of the iframe.